# How to find the rows with maximum values from multiple files having same structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some files (csv) which are of the same structure

```
  File 1           File 2           File 3           File 4
Id   Values      Id   Values      Id   Values      Id    Values 
A1    0.2        A2    0.1        A3    0.4        A4    0.7
B1    0.5        B2    0.4        B3    0.2        B4    0.1
C1    0.1        C2    0.8        C3    0.05       C4    0.3
D1    0.3        D2    0.1        D3    0.9        D4    0.2
```

Now from each of these files I require the maximum id and value from all the rows, i.e I need

```
Id  values
A4   0.7
B2   0.4
C2   0.8
D3   0.9
```

How to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
frames = [pd.read_csv(f'file{i}.csv') for i in range(1, 5)]
df = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
ix = df.values[:, 1::2].argmax(axis=1)
out = pd.concat([frames[k].iloc[[i]] for i, k in enumerate(ix)])
```

Produces:

```py
>>> out
   Id  Values
0  A4     0.7
1  B1     0.5
2  C2     0.8
3  D3     0.9
```

**Explanation**

The first line reads all the csv files into individual dataframes.

We temporarily make a `df` that is the horizontal concatenation of these frames:

```py
>>> df
   Id  Values  Id  Values  Id  Values  Id  Values
0  A1     0.2  A2     0.1  A3    0.40  A4     0.7
1  B1     0.5  B2     0.4  B3    0.20  B4     0.1
2  C1     0.1  C2     0.8  C3    0.05  C4     0.3
3  D1     0.3  D2     0.1  D3    0.90  D4     0.2
```

We then use `df.values[:, 1::2]` to get to only the numeric values as a `numpy` array, and take `argmax` of this for each column. The result is an index `ix` that indicates, for each row, which frame has the maximum:

```py
>>> ix
array([3, 0, 1, 2])
```

At this point, we can just assemble the rows by selecting the frame `k` that has the max for each row `i`.

**Vectorized alternative (look Ma, no loops! using a `numpy` 3D array)**

For better speed (if you have many frames), you may consider building and using a 3D `numpy` array to avoid the explicit loop when constructing the final result:

```py
z = df.values.reshape(df.shape[0], len(frames), -1)
ix = z[:, :, 1].argmax(axis=1)
out = pd.DataFrame(np.einsum('iij->ij', z[:, ix]), columns=frames[0].columns)
```

In this, `z` is a 3D array:

```py
>>> z
array([[['A1', 0.2],
        ['A2', 0.1],
        ['A3', 0.4],
        ['A4', 0.7]],

       [['B1', 0.5],
        ['B2', 0.4],
        ['B3', 0.2],
        ['B4', 0.1]],

       [['C1', 0.1],
        ['C2', 0.8],
        ['C3', 0.05],
        ['C4', 0.3]],

       [['D1', 0.3],
        ['D2', 0.1],
        ['D3', 0.9],
        ['D4', 0.2]]], dtype=object)
```

that is nice in that it lets us find the `argmax` in a more concise way:

```py
ix = z[:, :, 1].argmax(axis=1)
>>> ix
array([3, 0, 1, 2])
```

but more importantly, it then lets us select in one shot from the index `ix` (using `np.einsum` to get the desired diagonal) and obtain the rows we want:

```py
>>> np.einsum('iij->ij', z[:, ix])
array([['A4', 0.7],
       ['B1', 0.5],
       ['C2', 0.8],
       ['D3', 0.9]], dtype=object)
```

Then we just make a new dataframe with these values, and using the first frame to label the columns.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely more than one way to do what you want.  If the data is exactly the same looping through lists could get what you want.  My approach is to use dataframes.  For each 'category' (As, Bs etc) build a dataframe with those values and then the search for the max or min is easy.  You will need the pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd
# This function creates a small dataframe where each row is from a different file that you want to evaluate. It loads the row you want and skips the rest
def read_files(file_list, skipped):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Id', 'Values'])
    for file in file_list:
        df_temp = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=skipped)
        df = df.append(df_temp, ignore_index=True)
    return (df)

final_answers = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(4):
    skipped_list = [(2,3,4),(1,3,4), (1,2,4),(1,2,3)]
    file_list = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv', 'file4.csv']

    working_df = read_files(file_list, skipped_list[i])
    answer = working_df[working_df.Values == working_df.Values.max()]
    final_answers = final_answers.append(answer, ignore_index=True)

print(final_answers)
Output:
  Id Values
0 A4    0.7
1 B1    0.5
2 C2    0.8
3 D3    0.9
```

Some improvements - I specified the file names for simplicity but you could load files based on a pattern such as all *.csv if your data is all in one directory or get more complicated pattern such as 'starts with' and 'ends with' to load all files that you may need.  Also the skipped_list was pre-determined for simplicity.  A small loop could create the list so that much larger data-sets would work without the tediousness of filling out that list.